# JQuery date formatting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have  to format date as below using Jquery, I tried with Date.js and some more external JS but unable to do so:

```
Input value: 
Date val: 20150306 
Time :185900


Expected format:
time:  6.59 PM 
Date :Mar 06, 2015
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How would `20150306` ever become `Oct 06, 2015`?

Comment: @Magrangs basically tring to format a date and time using jquery

Comment: @Rory McCrossan its an example

Comment: Right, but how can `03` = `October`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if 03 == March , just wanted to show the format, anyway I have corrected

Comment: Try Moment.js, wonderful library

Comment: @KRR as Jeremy suggested, take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version (untested)

```
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],

date = "20150306",
time = "185900",

//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp
date_year = date.slice(0, 4),
date_month = date.slice(4, 6),
date_day = date.slice(6, 8),
time_hours = time.slice(0, 2),
time_mins = time.slice(2, 4),
time_secs = time.slice(4, 6),

//http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
dateObj = new Date(date_year, date_month, date_day, time_hours, time_mins, time_secs, 0),
dateString = [monthNames[dateObj.getMonth() - 1], " ", dateObj.getDate(), ", ", dateObj.getFullYear()].join(""),

//Bit of Math
timeHours = dateObj.getHours() % 12 || 12,
timeSuffix = time_hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM',
timeString = [timeHours, ':', time_mins, ' ', timeSuffix].join("");

console.log("Date: " +  dateString);
console.log("Time: " +  timeString);
```

Comment: Urgh... That hurts my eyes.